# npm script succeeds when I run a named task, but not when I run the cli commands it describes (node-sass)

Tags: npm, sass, yarnpkg, node-sass, npm-scripts

I have a build config for npm that runs a bunch of the commands, but it is failing. This is the npm script that seems to be the problem:

```json
"build-css": "node-sass src/styles/main.scss dist/static/css/main.css --output-style compressed",
```

If I run `yarn run build-css`, it will successfully compile the css.

But if I run the command inside of it explicitly:

```
node-sass src/styles/main.scss dist/static/css/main.css --output-style compressed
```

It says:

> `no such file or directory: node-sass`

This worked at one point and no longer does, and I'm not sure what changed.

Comment: If you run it with plain NPM, do you see the same issue?

Comment: Perhaps `node-sass` was previously installed globally and now it's not, hence why it worked at one point when running the command explicitly. Assuming that you `cd` to your project directory and `node-saas` is installed there.... Try running: `node_modules/.bin/node-sass src/styles/main.scss dist/static/css/main.css --output-style compressed` _(i.e. prefix the command to with the path to the executable in the local .bin folder)_

Comment: Rob - that worked, thanks - not sure what caused the issue, but this will get things working for me. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node-sass` was probably installed globally and now it's not - hence why it worked at one point when running the command explicitly.

A local copy of `node-sass` can be run by invoking the version which resides in the projects `node_modules/.bin` directory instead.

1. Firstly `cd` to your projects directory.
2. Run `node_modules/.bin/node-sass src/styles/main.scss dist/static/css/main.css --output-style compressed`

Note your original command has been prefixed with: `node_modules/.bin/`